# Getting java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

When I execute the following code, I get an exception. I think it is because I'm preparing in new statement with he same connection object. How should I rewrite this so that I can create a prepared statement AND get to use rs2? Do I have to create a new connection object even if the connection is to the same DB?

```
    try 
    {
        //Get some stuff
        String name = "";
        String sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `user` WHERE `id` = " + userId + " LIMIT 1;";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rs.next())
        {
            name = rs.getString("name");
        }

        String sql2 = "SELECT `id` FROM  `profiles` WHERE `id` =" + profId + ";";
        ResultSet rs2 = statement.executeQuery(sql2);
        String updateSql = "INSERT INTO `blah`............"; 
        PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement)connection.prepareStatement(updateSql);    

        while(rs2.next()) 
        { 
            int id = rs2.getInt("id");
            int stuff = getStuff(id);

            pst.setInt(1, stuff);
            pst.addBatch();

        }

        pst.executeBatch();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

private int getStuff(int id)
{

    try
    {   

            String sql = "SELECT ......;";
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            if(rs.next())
            {
                return rs.getInt("something");

            }
            return -1;
    }//code continues
```

Comment: it happens for the first time when while gets invoked?

Comment: No, it happens on the 2nd loop. Because within the while, I make another call to a private method that inits another ResultSet and executes more queries.

Comment: can you show up the rest of the code that is executed in the first iteration

Comment: Could the exception happen because of that other ResultSet?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is with the way you fetch data in `getStuff()`. Each time you visit `getStuff()` you obtain a fresh `ResultSet` but you don't close it.

This violates the expectation of the `Statement` class (see here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.

What makes things even worse is the `rs` from the calling code. It is also derived off-of the `statement` field but it is not closed.

Bottom line: you have several `ResultSet` pertaining to the same `Statement` object concurrently opened.

Comment: Cool. I created a new Statement in getStuff() and that solved the problem.

Comment: Have you tried closing the ResultSet? Seems like a cleaner approach than creating a new Statement.

Answer (score 12):

> A ResultSet object is automatically
>   closed when the Statement object that
>   generated it is closed, re-executed,
>   or used to retrieve the next result
>   from a sequence of multiple results.

I guess after `while(rs2.next())` you are trying to access something from rs1. But it's already closed since you reexecuted statement to get rs2 from it. Since you didn't close it, I beleive it's used again below.

Comment: Just added more code. I actually don't get anything from rs1 afterwards.

Comment: those ancient Java classes are so weirdly designed :(