# JDBC Exception: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, sql, exception, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840866/getting-java-sql-sqlexception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed)

I'm working on some code that is throwing `Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed` exceptions.  Here it is:

```
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT codigo FROM projecto WHERE nome='"
    + auxiliarNomes.elementAt(i).toString() + "'");
while (res.next()) {
    codigo = res.getString("codigo");
    stmt.executeUpdate("insert into categoriaprojectos values("
        + "'" + codigo + "'" + "," + "'" + Antena.RetornaCodigoProjecto() + "')");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Search "SQL injection" and find out why your SQL construction is wrong

Answer (score 7):

This is possible. Just use an extra connection and statement.

```
Statement statementOne = connectionOne.createStatement();
Statement statementTwo = connectionTwo.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSetOne = statementOne.executeQuery("select * from x");

while (resultSetOne.next()) {
    ResultSet resultSetTwo = statementTwo.executeQuery(String.format("select * from y where xy = %s", resultSetOne.getString(0)));

    while (resultSetTwo.next()) {
        String result = resultSetTwo.getString(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse a executeUpdate is also possible instead of a second Query

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a duplicate of [Getting java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840866/getting-java-sql-sqlexception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed). In brief, you cannot iterate over a `ResultSet` from some `Statement` and execute updates on the same `Statement` at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is very **dirty written**, you should use `PreparedStatements` with `parametrized SQL statements`, because without them there is big danger of **SQL Injection**. This approach is more faster, cleaner and much more safer!
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854285/getting-an-integer-from-mysql-select-statement/10855399#10855399)

And to your code, try to do like this, you should use `batch` for insert more than one operation.

```
String SEL_QUERY = "SELECT codigo FROM projecto WHERE nome= ?";
String UPDATE_QUERY = "INSERT INTO categoriaprojectos values(?)";

PreparedStatement ps,ps1 = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

ps = con.prepareStatement(SEL_QUERY);
ps.setYourType(<data>);
rs =stmt.executeQuery();
ps1 = con.prepareStatement(UPDATE_QUERY );
while(rs.next())
{
   ps1.setYourType(rs.getType());
   ps1.addBatch();
}
ps1.executeBatch();
```

You should use batch for this. It's faster, safer and more cleaner. `addBatch()` method adds a set of parameters to your `PreparedStatement` object's batch of commands.
You will be for example 4 inserts in batch and then you will execute them mass.This technique is named as **data clustering**