# Getting an Integer From MySQL Select Statement

Tags: java, mysql, database, integer

I would like to get an integer saved in my MySql DB into an Integer in Java. I have a Table, that includes PlayerName and Level. I would like to get The Level (Integer) From a Specific Player. And then Add Integer "Value" to it. Then put it back in the DB. My Code up to now is:

```
public void addinputPData(String loc, int value, Player player, String playername){
    //add input Player Data
    try{
        logm("Putting Kill Death Int Data into  " +player.getName() + "'s Profile!");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WebCom", "root", "MyPW");

            int ovalue = -1;    
        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT "+loc+" FROM PlayerData WHERE PlayerName='"+playername+"'");
        if(rs.next()){
            ovalue= rs.getInt(loc);
        }
        if(ovalue == -1){
            logm("Error Occured");

        }
        int nvalue = value + ovalue;

        String insert = "UPDATE PlayerData SET "+ loc + "='" + nvalue + "' WHERE PlayerName='" + playername + "'";

        stmt.executeUpdate(insert);

        con.close();

    }catch(Exception e){

        logm("Could Not Send Data To MYSQL DATABASE SERVER s: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I don't know why this won't work, Is there anything obvious that i am missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an exception? Nothing happens? We need more information.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What is occurring when it is run?

Answer (score 1):

So first what you must understand is that when you won't use `parametrized statements`, there is big danger of `SQL Injection`. So your code is very dirty written.
So anyway, use `PreparedStatement` with **parametrized** SQL statements for much more better performace. Now rewrite your code like this:

```
final String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT level FROM PlayerData WHERE PlayerName = ?";
final String UPDATE_QUERY = "UPDATE PlayerData SET level = ? WHERE PlayerName = ?";

public boolean dataMethod(String playerName) {
   Connection con = null;
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   int dataLevel = 0;

   try {

   // getConnection etc...
   ps = con.prepareStatement(SELECT_QUERY);
   ps.setString(1, playerName) // first param is order of ? param, starts with 1(not 0)
   rs = ps.executeQuery();
   while (rs.next()) {
      dataLevel = rs.getInt();
   }
   if (dataLevel > 0) {
       ps1 = con.prepareStatement(UPDATE_QUERY);
       ps1.setInt(1, dataLevel);
       ps1.setString(2, playerName);
       ps1.executeUpdate();   
   }
   return true;
   }
   catch (SQLExcetion ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      return false;
   }
   finally {
      if (con != null) {
         con.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Step by step, first init your statement, sets parameters if you have then when you use select, you will retrieve data in `ResultSet` that is table of data generated with query. imlicitly cursor in `ResultSet` is position before first row so you have to use `next()` method to go on current row and with the help of getter method you add data from `ResultSet` to your variable. Then you check if it's correct, if do, init second statement and execute it. And that's all.

But you should consider when you use more that 1 operation, sets `autoCommit` on false and all operations will do in one `Transaction`, because implicitly in `JDBC` is one operation = one transaction. And second, you should consider to use **SQL stored procedures** for add any data, update data or delete. It's more safer yet and less code. So let database working when it able to do it and also it's faster of course.
At the last, really you should think about this approach and makes your code more safer, faster and cleaner. Not have look on simplicity but on efficiency, compability and security.

More about [SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

And when you decided right to use **stored procedure**, you can use it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SOME_NAME(VARCHAR v_name PlayerData.name%type)
AS
BEGIN
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
   // body
   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK;
END;
```

So now you have to create String for call procedure.

```
final String CALL_SOMENAME = "{call SOME_NAME(?)}";
```

Then intead of `PreparedStatement` you have to use `CallableStatement` that is `interface` used to execute SQL stored procedures.

```
cs.prepareCall(CALL_SOMENAME); // Creates a cs object for calling db stored procedures
cs.setString(1, playerName);
cs.execute();
```

I don't know why many people searching the easiest way to do something and don't look at performance and readability of code.

Regards

Comment: Although this code seems good at what it does i don't think that it is what i meant. Now The Situation: I have a Counter in my database and Integer Level (Represented by the Variable loc) and String PlayerName in the table. i want that every time that method is called it gets the level, adds 1 to it and then submits it back into the DB. That is where i fail.  But thank you for the help anyways, maybe you can help me with this too. - Jan

Answer (score 0):

In the UPDATE statement, you're inserting the value for the "loc" column as a string (there are single quotes around the value).  If the database column is an integer, then this could be causing a problem.

**Tip:** JDBC provides a class called `PreparedStatement`.  This class allow you to build SQL queries safely.  It makes sure that all user input is properly escaped in order to avoid security vulnerabilities.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE PlayerData SET " + loc + " = ? WHERE PlayerName = ?");
ps.setInt(1, nvalue);
ps.setString(2, playername);
ps.execute();
```