# ResultSet, null pointer exception and SQLException operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, sql

Im new in java and SQL, Im repeating a problem that i don't know how to avoid it:

assume i want to make two executeQuery, one inside the other in the getRequestsFromDB method i make the first executeQuery and in the second method isProfessionalHasThatProfession i make the second executeQuery:

```
 private Vector<ClientRequest> getRequestsFromDB() throws SQLException {
    Vector<ClientRequest> retVal = new Vector<ClientRequest>();
    ResultSet result = null;
    try {
        for (int i=0 ; i<_userBean.getProfession().length ; ++i ){
            result = _statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+_dbName+"."+CLIENTS_REQUEST_TABLE+" WHERE "+CLIENTS_REQUEST_T_PROFESSION+"='"+_userBean.getProfession()[i]+"'");               
            while(result.next()){ //HERE IN THE SECOND LOOP GETTING NULL EXCEPTION

                if(isProfessionalHasThatProfession(result.getString(CLIENTS_REQUEST_T_PROFESSION))){
                    retVal.add(cr);
                    ClientRequest cr = new ClientRequest
                            (result.getString(CLIENTS_REQUEST_T_CLIENT_ID), 
                            result.getString(CLIENTS_REQUEST_T_CITY),
                            result.getString(CLIENTS_REQUEST_T_DATE),
                            result.getString(CLIENTS_REQUEST_T_PROFESSION));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

the second function:

```
private boolean isProfessionalHasThatProfession(String profession) throws SQLException {             
    ResultSet result = null;
    try {
        result = _statement.executeQuery("SELECT "+WORKER_PROFESSIONS_T_PROFESSION+" FROM "+_dbName+"."+WORKER_PROFESSIONS_TABLE+" WHERE "+WORKER_PROFESSIONS_T_PROFESSIONAL_ID+"='"+_userBean.getProId()+"'");
        while(result.next()){
            if(result.getString(1).equals(profession)){
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return false;
}
```

in the second loop im getting a SQLException: "operation not allowed after ResultSet closed", i have tried:
close in finally the result with result.close() but also i get exception null pointer exception.

i'm really don't know how to deal with that, ideas?
Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291619/jdbc-exception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840866/getting-java-sql-sqlexception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed.  Also you should really be using parametrized SQL statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

youre reusing `_statement` (which i assume is global?) to get 2 different `ResultSet`s, but then you return to the 1st `ResultSet` (in the outside function) after you got the 2nd (inside the inner function, which automatically closed the 1st) - try using 2 separate statements

Answer (score 0):

Check this link :http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.

And you are reusing your statement

Answer (score 0):

See this quote, from the [ResultSet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

- A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

Looks like you are using a class, or global, scope Statement (`_statement`), which backs both the resultset you are trying to iterate over, and query details of some sort for each entry in the resultset in your `isProfessionalHasThatProfession` method.  but when you execute a new query with the same `Statement`, your old ResultSet is closed.

So, you'll need a separate statement for the second query.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java API:

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects.

So you have to generate a new `Statement` for the second `ResultSet`. Please don't forget to close the `Statement`s respectively.