# ResultSetImpl throws NullPointerException

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector, connector-j

i'm running mysql 5.5 with mysql 5.1.18 connector.
a simple query of style

`select * from my_table where column_a in ('aaa','bbb',...) and column b=1;`

is executed from within java application. the query returns a resultset of 25k rows, 8 columns in each. while reading the results in while loop

```
while(rs.next())
{
    MyObject c= new MyObject();  
    c.setA(rs.getString("A"));
    c.setB(rs.getString("B"));
    c.setC(rs.getString("C"));
    ...
}
```

a following exception is thrown, usually during the first loops, but never in the same row:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5720)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5610)
```

i took a look at the source code in ResultSetImpl.java:5720 and i see the following:

```
switch (metadata.getSQLType())
```

where metadata is

```
Field metadata = this.fields[internalColumnIndex];
```

and getSQLType is a logic-less getter returning an int. what's interesting, is that the same metadata object is called numerous times several lines above with other getters, and throws no exceptions.

btw, there is no problem with the query above while ran directly within mysql.
application runs in aws.

any ideas how to solve this? 
thanks.

Comment: i tried to reproduce this on a local server, but everything worked fine. i am going to limit the number of values in the "in()" part of the query and execute multiple selects until all selects are done.

Comment: I got a similar error with mysql-connector-java 5.1.34:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:757)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5240)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5162)
                at (my code here)

I think it was probably caused by an earlier exception:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

Comment: @atarno Did you ever find a solution to your question? I got a similar exception using mysql-connector 5.1.40. My question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616564/occasional-nullpointerexception-in-com-mysql-jdbc-resultsetimpl-checkcolumnbound).

Comment: @Shannon Did you ever find a solution to this exception? I got a similar exception using mysql-connector 5.1.40. My question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616564/occasional-nullpointerexception-in-com-mysql-jdbc-resultsetimpl-checkcolumnbound).

Comment: @Eran I don't remember exactly because that was a while ago, but as I recall the problem was with a multithread application which was incorrectly sharing JDBC objects and incorrectly responding to exceptions. You need to be careful with how you deal with exceptions, and you need to be sure that if a connection or a result set is closed that another thread doesn't continue to try to use it.

Comment: In my case was using the shared connection between threads, I changed to share a `Datasource`, and every thread from the `Datasource` get a new connection, and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue, using a Spring Data CrudRepository, retrieving a Stream of results from a MySql database running on AWS RDS, with a moderately convoluted query.

It would also throw at a non-deterministic row, after about 30k rows.

I resolved this issue by annotating the calling method with @Transactional.

Although you're not using JPA, setting up a transaction for your database access may help your issue.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this error is a result of locked table while trying to read/write simultaneously from the same table. You need to add a pool for every request or some wait time between every operation to the MySQL.

Related answer as well: 
[Getting java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840866/getting-java-sql-sqlexception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed)