# NullPointerException error for an SQL code

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

I've got this form which contains three text fields and two radio buttons. The form is supposed to calculate the bill amounts for a customer. I've written the following code and it shows a NullPointerException error.

```
int noproduct;
double totalprice, price, shipcharge;
try{
    Connection connection=getConnection();
    stmt=connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("Select count(ProductName) from buy;");
    ResultSet rs2=stmt.executeQuery("Select sum(price) as TPrice from buy;");
    noproduct=rs1.getInt("count(ProductName)");
    NoProducts.setText(""+noproduct);
    price=rs2.getDouble("TPrice");
    shipcharge=3 * noproduct;
    ShipCharges.setText(""+shipcharge);
    totalprice=price+shipcharge;
    TotalPrice.setText(""+totalprice);
    if(CashRB.isSelected()){
        totalprice=totalprice+(5*noproduct);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have paid the bill by Cash!");
    }
    else if(CCardRB.isSelected()){
        totalprice=totalprice-(5*noproduct);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have paid the bill using Credit Card!");
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally{}
```

This line in specific shows the error:

```
noproduct=rs1.getInt("count(ProductName)");
```

I need an alternate code to display the same result as this.

As well as it shows these errors, which I don't really understand what they are:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.buildIndexMapping(ResultSetImpl.java:709)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1069)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2734)
```

Can anyone help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Error at line 2734.. Did you consider refactoring code and breaking it into smaller parts?

Comment: @svz: that's the MySQL JDBC driver code, not the OP's code.

Comment: @LuluLala: the other statement assigns an alias to the sum. Why don't you do the same thing in the first statement and assign an alias to the count?

Comment: @JBNizet, huh, I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this to

```
 rs1.next();
 noproduct=rs1.getInt(1);
```

and [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840866/getting-java-sql-sqlexception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed)

there is one `ResultSet` is allowed for one `Statement`. may be you got Exception in this case. because you used ResultSet res1 and rs2.

Comment: It showed this error:                                    `java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this. Do you mean the code for the connection I made for the form with MySQL?

Comment: there is one `ResultSet` is allowed for one `Statement`. may be you got Exception in this case. because you used ResultSet rs1 and rs2.

Comment: But it doesn't work if I use only one `ResultSet`. Is there any alternative for that?

Comment: if you use only one result set what exception you got..?

Comment: It worked! I replaced `rs1` with `rs` which I used for both the queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("Select count(ProductName) as NoOfProducts from buy;");
rs1.next();
noproduct=rs1.getInt("NoOfProducts");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `rs1.next()` cursor to invoke value.

```
 while(rs1.next()){
   noproduct=rs1.getInt("count(ProductName)");
 }
```

Comment: It shows a warning that `noproducts` might not be initialized for the next line.

Comment: The warning is because you declared `noproduct` without default value. Assign a default value in case the code does not execute the while block (`noproduct = 0;` before the while)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error occurs when you directly access resultset without itrating the it.

You can solve problem by itrate the resultset and get value:

```
while (resultSet.next()) 
        {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
            response.put("dish_title", resultSet.getString("dish_title"));
            int remainingQuantity =  resultSet.getInt("quantity") -  
        }
```