# How can I solve this exception? java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed my code is:

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
package SchoolManagement;

import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Statement;

public class sampleConnection
 {

public ResultSet executeStatement(String SQL) throws SQLException, 
ClassNotFoundException 
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/school_management?allowMultiQueries=true","root",""); 

 Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

boolean results = stmt.execute(SQL);

int rsCount = 0;

ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();

try {

do {

if(results) {

rsCount++;

           System.out.println("RESULT SET #" + rsCount);

           while (rs.next()) {

              System.out.println(rs.getString("Username") );

              out.println("rs---"+rs.next());

           }

        }

        System.out.println();

        results = stmt.getMoreResults();

        } while(results);

      }

   catch (SQLException e) {

     out.println(e.toString());

   }

   out.println("============="+rs.next());

   return rs;

}

 public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{  

    sampleConnection mc= new sampleConnection();

     String SQL = "select * from login;select * from login";

     ResultSet rs2=mc.executeStatement(SQL);

}   
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that code? The base principle is when `ResultSet#next()` returns false, you can not call `next()` again (see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()): "When a call to the next method returns false, the cursor is positioned after the last row. Any invocation of a ResultSet method which requires a current row will result in a SQLException being thrown.")

Comment: This ia a typo "select * from login;select * from login"; no

Comment: I want to return the resultset to another jsp page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840866/getting-java-sql-sqlexception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed)

Comment: Don't return `ResultSet`, never. If you want a list of username for your jsp then return a List of String and use the common [JDBC query "pattern"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html). Some reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
 while (rs.next()) {

          System.out.println(rs.getString("Username") );

          out.println("rs---"+rs.next());

       }
```

won't work. rs.next() returns moves the cursor position one further [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()).
You will need something like `rs.getInt(String columnLabel)` to get the datas from that position in the result set.

Second:
The result set is closed because of getMoreResults()

> Moves to this Statement object's next result, returns true if it is a ResultSet object, and implicitly closes any current ResultSet object(s) obtained with the method getResultSet. [See: Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults())

Accessing the rs after that call it will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

You shall not use two selects in one request:

```
String SQL = "select * from login;select * from login";
```

This does not allow you to read trough the result of the select twice.

resultSets are forward-only in almost all the cases for performance reasons, therefore you likely can not "go back" and re-read the same data again.

If you need the output of this select multiple times, the best approach is:

- run it only once
- collect the result in a loop and put to a container, e.g. List
- return that list