# Creating an object in java database error

Tags: java, mysql

I created loadTransaksi methods, this method will return ArrayList

this is my code

```
public ArrayList<Transaksi> loadTransaksi() {
    try {
        ArrayList<Transaksi> daftarTransaksi = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "select * from transaksi";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            Transaksi t = new Transaksi(rs.getInt(4), this.getAccount(rs.getString(5)), this.getPelanggan(rs.getInt(6)),rs.getDate(1), rs.getDate(2), rs.getLong(3));
        }
        return daftarTransaksi;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("terjadi kesalahan saat load transaksi");
    }
}
```

but i get an error when calling getAccount and getPelanggan method

this is my code for getAccount

```
     public Pegawai getAccount(String username) {
    try {
        Pegawai p = null;
        String query = "select * from pegawai Where username ='" + username +"'";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        if (rs.next()) {
            p = new Pegawai(rs.getString(3), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(1));
        }
        return p;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("terjadi kesalahan saat load peserta");
    }
}
```

and this one for getPelanggan

```
    public Pelanggan getPelanggan(int id_pelanggan){
    try {
        String query = "select * from pelanggan where id_pelanggan='" + id_pelanggan +"'";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

        if (rs.next()) {
            Pelanggan p = new Pelanggan(rs.getInt(2) ,rs.getString("nama"), this.getCucian(rs.getInt(3)));
            return p;
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("terjadi kesalahan saat load pelanggan");
    }
}
```

in getPelanggan method i also called getCucian and this is the code

```
    public Cucian getCucian(int id_cucian){
    try {
        String query = "select * from cucian Where id_cucian ='" + id_cucian +"'";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        if (rs.next()) {
            Cucian c = new Cucian(rs.getInt("id_cucian"), rs.getInt("berat"));
            System.out.println("Cucian " + c.getId());
            return c;
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("terjadi kesalahan saat load peserta");
    }
}
```

I'm new in java and mySQL and still learning it. hope you guys can help me. thank you :D
Update ----
This is the Transaksi class

```
public class Transaksi {
private int kodeTransaksi;
private Pegawai pegawai;
private Pelanggan pelanggan;
private java.util.Date tglMasuk;
private java.util.Date tglKeluar;
private long bayar;

public Transaksi(Pegawai pegawai, Pelanggan pelanggan, Date tglMasuk, Date tglKeluar, long bayar) {
    this.pegawai = pegawai;
    this.pelanggan = pelanggan;
    this.tglMasuk = tglMasuk;
    this.tglKeluar = tglKeluar;
    this.bayar = bayar;
}


public Transaksi(int kodeTransaksi, Pegawai pegawai, Pelanggan pelanggan, java.util.Date tglMasuk, java.util.Date tglKeluar, long bayar) {
    this.kodeTransaksi = kodeTransaksi;
    this.pegawai = pegawai;
    this.pelanggan = pelanggan;
    this.tglMasuk = tglMasuk;
    this.tglKeluar = tglKeluar;
    this.bayar = bayar;
}

public int getKodeTransaksi() {
    return kodeTransaksi;
}

public Pegawai getPegawai() {
    return pegawai;
}

public Pelanggan getPelanggan() {
    return pelanggan;
}

public java.util.Date getTglMasuk() {
    return tglMasuk;
}

public java.util.Date getTglKeluar() {
    return tglKeluar;
}

public long getBayar() {
    return bayar;
}

public void setBayar(long bayar) {
    this.bayar = bayar;
}


public void setKodeTransaksi(int kodeTransaksi) {
    this.kodeTransaksi = kodeTransaksi;
}

public void setPegawai(Pegawai pegawai) {
    this.pegawai = pegawai;
}

public void setPelanggan(Pelanggan pelanggan) {
    this.pelanggan = pelanggan;
}

public void setTglMasuk(java.util.Date tglMasuk) {
    this.tglMasuk = tglMasuk;
}

public void setTglKeluar(java.util.Date tglKeluar) {
    this.tglKeluar = tglKeluar;
}

public long getTotalHarga(){
    return bayar;
}
```

}

and this is the error message
https://imghost.io/image/abEdo
imghost.io/image/abJy0

Comment: "i get an error" what is it??

Comment: this is the error message https://imghost.io/image/abEdo

Comment: in method `loadTransaksi` in catch block add `e.printStackTrace();` line before `throw new IllegalArgumentException("terjadi kesalahan saat load transaksi");`

Comment: can you show us `Transaksi` class ?

Comment: the error image you uploaded is not exact cause...

Comment: @ELITE I added e.printStackTrace(); and it makes the error information more clearly, it says the ResultSet is already closed
https://imghost.io/image/abJy0

Comment: @JohnJoe updated

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840866/getting-java-sql-sqlexception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed

Comment: @ELITE Thank you for your help!

Comment: so have you solved ?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes, it is, thank you!