# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed when parsing

Tags: scala

I am trying to parse ResultSet fetched from a database into a case class as below.

```
val records = db.withConnection { conn =>
  val rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery()
  Iterator.continually(rs).takeWhile(_.next()).map(parseRecord)
}

def parseRecord(rs: ResultSet) = {
  SomeCaseClass(
     col1 = rs.getString("Column1"),
     col2 = rs.getString("Column2"),
          :
  )
}
```

With this code, I get an error saying `SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed` within the `parseRecord` method for some reason.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: While I certainly do not know what is happening. I would suggest using a library instead of using the **JDBC** directly.

Comment: You can try using slick for Db connection. Sample project can be found here: https://github.com/SangeetaGulia/Student-CRUD-Slick

Comment: I have been using Slick and ScalikeJDBC for some projects, but my question is not about asking the recommended tools wrapped around JDBC.

Comment: I believe this might be the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840866/getting-java-sql-sqlexception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed - you use `.map` after `.next` so you are trying to transform a row after you told JDBC to move on.